# Icon color not working in native base header buttons

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am using [NativeBase Header](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#header-def-headref). In header, I have buttons like cart and wishlist. But I am not able to change the color of that icons.

Here is my header code :

```js
<Header>
  <Left>
    <Button transparent onPress={props.onMenuPress}>
      <Icon type="Ionicons" name="menu" color="#ff0000" />
    </Button>
  </Left>
  <Body>
    <Title>{props.title}</Title>
  </Body>
  <Right>
    <Button transparent onPress={props.onWishlistPress}>
      <Icon name="heart" active={false} color="#ff0000" />
    </Button>
    <Button transparent onPress={props.onCartPress} icon>
      <Icon name="cart" active={false} color="#ff0000" />
    </Button>
  </Right>
</Header>
```

Please anyone can tell me what is the problem here ?

Comment: Instead of color, try tintColor

Comment: Sorry, but it is not working @SandipSingh.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is shown in the `Native-base` document. For Icon, `Native-base` use the `React-native-vector-icons` module, which allows you to set `colors` and `sizes` through the `style`.

### Icon

Perfect, crisp, high definition icons and pixel ideal fonts powered by `NativeBase` to preserve matters very high first-rate. You will continually have pixel perfect icons on your initiatives.
Here is a repo that lists down icons of available `react-native-vector-icons` icon families. Repo

Uses Ionicons from React Native Vector Icons

### Exmaple

```js
 <Icon name='home' />
 <Icon ios='ios-menu' android="md-menu" style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'red'}}/>
 <Icon type="FontAwesome" name="home" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I just added color with `style` and it's working.

Comment: @KishanBharda I'm glad help to you. I hope you get a good app.